# VisualSVN got corrupted

Tags: svn, visualsvn, corrupt

We're running VisualSVN server, and last night it seemed to have gotten corrupted.  From what we can gather, the "current" file is what got corrupted, and we can't figure out how to rebuild this.

It consists of a single line of text, broken into 3 sections.  The first one is the current revision, and that is there now, but the other two sections are missing, and hard to deduce.

I finding it hard to swallow that there is no way to rebuild this file from the existing file structure.  All the revisions and files are present, it's just that "current" file that looks out of whack.

The "current" file I'm referring to is in the "db" folder under the repository folder.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you think this is the only corruption? chances are that it's not going to be the case - restore from backups and continue from there.

If you need to keep your changes committed since the last backup, you can hack in the repo files added to the db/revs abnd revprops directory, but you'll need to edit the curent file - you might want to ask collabnet for some support in this extreme case. If you can, just get the latest files and re-commit them after restoring the backups.

Or.. if you don't have a backup. Firstly, allow me to laugh heartily in your general direction for being so foolish. (especially when svnsync is so easy to setup and run)

The current file contains just the rev number of the current revision. This should be the same as the biggest numbered file in your db\revs directory. That's all, no extra stuff shoud be in there.

Comment: We ended up having to restore from backup, and luckily, experienced no loss due to when the failure happened and when the backup was taken.  The db/current file stayed the same, so yeah, I don't think that was the corruption now.  Anyways, I appreciate you answering.

Comment: good for you having backups, but I recommend the svnsync option - google for it, its very easy to get going and bascially keeps a incrementally updated, hot-copy of your repo. Well worth setting it up.